# Installing Anaconda on a Chromebook

Tags: python, chrome-os

So I'm not sure if this is the right place for my question since I'm using Chrome OS, but I've put it in developer mode and opened a shell, which looks very reminiscent of a Unix shell.  I've never really used Unix or Linux though so I don't really know what I'm talking about.

Anyway, I did all this so I could install Anaconda on it and, in following instructions I found elsewhere, typed `cd /usr` then `sudo chmod a+rw local` then `cd ~/Downloads` then `bash Anaconda-3-4.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`.  It ran for a while and was seemingly successful but at a certain point hit the following error:

```
./Anaconda3-4.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 450: /home/chronos/user/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.1-0/bin/python: Permission denied
ERROR:
cannot execute native linux-64 binary, output from 'uname -a' is:
Linux localhost 3.10.18 #1 SMP Sat Apr 9 15:59:53 PDT 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2840 @ 2.16GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

I basically got that some kind of a permission thng was going on and guessed that maybe I need to prepend `sudo` onto the command.  So then I executed `sudo bash Anaconda-3-4.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` and now get the error

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root/anaconda3’: 

Read-only file system
ERROR: Could not create directory: /root/anaconda3
```

[Edit: In response to a question in the comments, here is the result of entering `cat proc/mounts`.

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / ext2 ro,relatime 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=981424k,nr_inodes=245356,mode=755 0 0
none /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmp /tmp tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
run /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=755 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,gid=236,mode=750 0 0
shmfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/stateful_partition ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,commit=600,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p8 /usr/share/oem ext4 ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /home ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,commit=600,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mapper/encstateful /mnt/stateful_partition/encrypted ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,discard,commit=600,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mapper/encstateful /var ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,discard,commit=600,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mapper/encstateful /home/chronos ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,discard,commit=600,data=ordered 0 0
media /media tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /usr/local ext4 rw,nodev,relatime,commit=600,data=ordered 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=755 0 0
none /dev/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
debugfs /run/debugfs_gpu debugfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,gid=236,mode=750 0 0
/home/.shadow/17347860ad35b4ae57db54c3317448c89715bfeb/vault /home/.shadow/17347860ad35b4ae57db54c3317448c89715bfeb/mount ecryptfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,ecryptfs_sig=41185a1f9e90f57e,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=d1784311b40eb85a,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs 0 0
/home/.shadow/17347860ad35b4ae57db54c3317448c89715bfeb/vault /home/chronos/user ecryptfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,ecryptfs_sig=41185a1f9e90f57e,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=d1784311b40eb85a,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs 0 0
/home/.shadow/17347860ad35b4ae57db54c3317448c89715bfeb/vault /home/user/17347860ad35b4ae57db54c3317448c89715bfeb ecryptfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,ecryptfs_sig=41185a1f9e90f57e,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=d1784311b40eb85a,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs 0 0
/home/.shadow/17347860ad35b4ae57db54c3317448c89715bfeb/vault /home/chronos/u-17347860ad35b4ae57db54c3317448c89715bfeb ecryptfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,ecryptfs_sig=41185a1f9e90f57e,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=d1784311b40eb85a,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs 0 0
/home/.shadow/17347860ad35b4ae57db54c3317448c89715bfeb/vault /home/root/17347860ad35b4ae57db54c3317448c89715bfeb ecryptfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,ecryptfs_sig=41185a1f9e90f57e,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=d1784311b40eb85a,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs 0 0
tmpfs /run/crw tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,size=128k,mode=700 0 0
```

And the result of `ls -ld /home/chronos/user/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.1-0/bin /home/chronos/user/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.1-0/bin/python` is

```
/home/chronos/user/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.1-0/bin/python 
drwxr-xr-x 2 chronos chronos 4096 Apr 22 21:00 /home/chronos/user/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.1-0/bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 chronos chronos    9 Dec  7 12:18 /home/chronos/user/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.1-0/bin/python -> python3.5
```

]

Comment: ChromeOS is a Unix system inside with restrictions that make it impossible to interact with it like a normal Unix system. I think developer mode makes it back into a Unix system, but I'm not very familiar with it. What's the output of `cat /proc/mounts` and `ls -ld /home/chronos/user/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.1-0/bin /home/chronos/user/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.1-0/bin/python ` ?

Comment: @Gilles Below is the result of the former.

Comment: Actually I can't paste it because it's very large.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: The `noexec` option on the mounts is the culprit: it prevents any file from being executable, no matter what its permissions are. Google doesn't want you to install software. You need to jailbreak the device somehow.

Comment: @Gilles I just installed Crouton and it was able to successfully install Anaconda. Only thing now is that I can't figure out how to launch it to get to Spyder or notebooks.

Comment: For non-Intel Chromebooks: Arm chips / 32 bit support not really there for Anaconda yet, try installing matplotlib and see how far you get. Guy here from Continuum at a HPC workshop says they are trying to bring Anaconda to ARM but not very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can search for the program in the "run program" menu of a desktop such as xfce.
I used Crouton too, but I find it a lot easier to run programs like Python in a dual-boot Linux environment. If you have an x86 chromebook, check out chrx.org. If it's ARM based, check out https://github.com/com-py/Hibuntu or Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Use path `/usr/local/anaconda3` for the installation path.

If you use `/home/chronos/usr/` you will get the error.